# using theme for Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, themes

I saw few themes demo in fullcalendar download package. In my application i have different calendars like Leave calendar , travel calendar and events calendar. I want to use different theme for each calendar. i set

> theme: true

in my coding but exactly i dont know how to use the particular theme for that calendar.
For ex, i want to use bootstrap 3 - Lumen theme for event calendar, where to get and include that css file. Or i have to make my own css theme file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#ConfCalendarBlock').fullCalendar({      
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,listMonth'
        },

        theme: true,    
        themeSystem:'bootstrap3',        
        height:400,
        editable: true, 
        displayEventTime: false,        

        events: modJs.getConfJsonUrl(),     

        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loadingConfCalendarBlock').show();
            else $('#loadingConfCalendarBlock').hide();
        },

        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {

                modJs.getdayclick(date.format());               
        },          
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) { 
            modJs.geteventclick(calEvent.id);
        },   

    }); 
});
```

All my link files is included in header.php file

```
 <link href="<?=BASE_URL?>themecss/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=BASE_URL?>js/jquery2.0.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=BASE_URL?>js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <!--fullcalendar-->

    <link href="<?=BASE_URL?>js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?=BASE_URL?>js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
    <script src="<?=BASE_URL?>js/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?=BASE_URL?>js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `theme: true` is deprecated as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/themeSystem/ . Again as per that page, once you set the theme system to bootstrap, then "The Bootstrap CSS file must be separately loaded in its own <link> tag.". Have you done that? You can get a pre-made theme from anywhere online which is giving them away, or you can make your own custom theme. It's completely up to you.

Comment: i include all my fullcalendar files in header.php.  my question might be silly..i couldnt understand this point..  "The Bootstrap CSS file must be separately loaded in its own <link> tag.". Where to do that and how to do that?

Comment: You must download the bootstrap CSS theme file, from wherever you source it (or use your own, if you make your own), put it in the folder with your web page, and then reference it with a tag, e g. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">` just like any CSS file. Normally you put the inside the `<head>` tag of your page. This is pretty basic HTML stuff, if you don't know how to add a stylesheet then maybe it's time to take an introductory tutorial before you dive into something complex like fullCalendar.

Comment: The sentence inside the double quotes made me to think that there is some other way of adding of css files .But it refers the normal way. Just a misunderstanding. Thank your for your response.

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to clarify